# How to insert value based on comparing two column with respective table (SQL Script)?

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql

I have two tables called `user` and `customer`.

In userTable i have

```
id |   username   |    password    | role_id 
----+--------------+----------------+---------
  1 | sharam       | asdfgh         |        
  2 | ghandhi      | iiiooo         |        
  3 | amir         | Qwertyuiop@1yy |       2
  4 | raju         | Qwertyuiop@1yy |       2
  5 | somu         | Qwertyuiop@1yy |       2
  6 | guna.        | Qwertyuiop@1yy |       2
```

In the customerTable I have

```
    Name    |  user_name   |    password     |       email        | phone_number | user_id 
------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+---------
 MansiMansi | sharam       | Qwertyuiop@1yy  | mansi@mansyiy.com  | 8992637877   |        
 MansiMansi | ghandhi      | Qwertyuop@1yy   | mansi@mansyi.com   | 8992637857   |        
 MansiMansi | amir         | Qwertyuop@1yyg  | mansi@mansyig.com  | 8992537857   |        
 MansiMansi | raju         | Qwertyuhop@1yyg | manshi@mansyig.com | 8692537857   |
```

Here I want to compare **user_name** in **customerTable** and **username** in **userTable** ,if both are same, I need to insert **id** from **userTable** into **user_id** in customerTable.

now result should be after executing the script... my **customerTable** should like...

```
    Name    |  user_name   |    password     |       email        | phone_number | user_id 
------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+---------
 MansiMansi | sharam       | Qwertyuiop@1yy  | mansi@mansyiy.com  | 8992637877   |  1      
 MansiMansi | ghandhi      | Qwertyuop@1yy   | mansi@mansyi.com   | 8992637857   |  2     
 MansiMansi | amir         | Qwertyuop@1yyg  | mansi@mansyig.com  | 8992537857   |  3     
 MansiMansi | raju         | Qwertyuhop@1yyg | manshi@mansyig.com | 8692537857   |  4
```

so friends, I need SQL script for this problem, especially **POSTGRES** script. and don't use **ANY JOINS ** concept, please.

`insert into registered_customer(user_id) select id from usertable where username in (select user_name from registered_customer);` i tried this, but its not workings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you would use:

```
update customertable c
    set user_id = u.id
    from usertable u
    where u.username = c.username;
```

Your code references an additional table that is not described in the question.

Comment: Awesome !!! It's working, Thank you so much. & one problem we faced it work in postgres, but not work in the h2 database... we using spring boot... so can you please help with us to make this script work on both h2 & postgress database.

Comment: @NatheeshkumarRangasamy . . . You should ask a new question specifically about H2.